# Problem with JS and whitespace - Ruby on Rails and JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a huge problem and don't know how to handle it. Look at the code below:

```
<div class="input-control row">
  <% ["Oneword", "With whitespace"].each_with_index do |answer, index| %>
    <%= label_tag "q7_#{index}", answer, class: "btn btn-reply question7", data: { "scroll-nav": "8", "question": "question_7", "answer": answer } do %>
      <%= radio_button_tag :question_7, answer, false, id: "q7_#{index}", class: "toggle" %>
      <%= answer %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So, this is a Rails project and i have to get that answer when it's clicked and for that i code some JS right here (The form radio don't get true because of Scroolit that have `e.preventDefault()`; and I have several questions)

```
$('body').on('click','[data-scroll-nav]', function(e){
  var question = $(e.target).attr('data-question');
  var answer = $(e.target).attr('data-answer');

  if(question && answer) {
    console.log($('input:radio[name=' + question + ']').filter('[value=' + answer + ']').prop('checked', true));
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  doScroll(e);
});
```

With the 0 index word it works, but with 1 index it does not work, and debugging it I think it's because of whitespace. How can i handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but I think you need to wrap `question` and `answer` in quotes for the selectors:

```js
$('input:radio[name="' + question + '"]').filter('[value="' + answer + '"]')
```

Notice the `"` added around the variable parts.

Comment: Still nothing guys, it returns that:
 "question"=>"", "answer"=>"", "controller"=>"pages/categories", "action"=>"search_result"}

Comment: I don't get you comment, in the code you show there's no form submission or anything, what's triggering that request? what do you see in the console with that console.log? is the input getting checked? is it showing the right thing?